# nested foreach loop, with php and laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am having problem with my nested foreach loop,  I have this code of my controller retrieving the values of two columns in separate table in my database.

What I want is to compare each values against the other table vice versa,...

```
table1             table2
some column1       some column2 
 a                  b
 b                  b
 c                  c
```

My desired output would be if the values of two columns compare, if it is true then output "match" otherwise "mismatch".

Here the attempt, but it doesn't work, only the last item in both tables column are being compared. i think i am missing with my nested loops.

///snippet///

**controller**

```
$temp_answers = array();
$answers = array();

$temp_answers = Tempanswer::where('subject_id', $subject_id)
                             ->where('student_id', $student_id)
                             ->lists('temp_answer');

$answers = Question::where('subject_slug', $subject->slug)
                             ->lists('letteranswer');

foreach ($temp_answers as $temp_answer) {

    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        if($answer == $temp_answer){
            $flag = 'match';
        }else 
            $flag = 'mismatch';
    }
    echo $flag.' ';

 }
```

Comment: `$flag` variable overwrites on each `foreach` iteration. Use array to store flags

Comment: Change `$flag = 'match';` to a simple `echo 'match';` also do this for the `mismatch` and loose the `echo $flag;` If you layout your code with sensible indentation like above, the error becomes so much easier to see

Comment: it was for debugging porpuses, that not actually the real score, theres my pivot table i want to insert something base on the result of nested loops

Comment: @RiggsFolly is my nested foreach correct sir? despite of those variables?

Comment: Basically you're comparing every given answer with every possible answer. That doesn't really make sense, there's no point in comparing the given answer for question 4 to the actual answer of question 2.

Comment: yes ur correct it doesnt make sense comparing number of answer greater than the number of question, its cleary dont make sense, but where did you get that 4 answer with 2 question? i think ur barkin at the wrong tree ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMIIW.
You want to check table1 and table2 is match. So if its not match you will get message "mismatch"

**Assumption 1**: if each data from table1 is compared with all data in table2.

```
foreach ($temp_answers as $temp_answer) {

    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        if($answer == $temp_answer){
            $flag = 'match';
        }else {
            $flag = 'mismatch';
            break;
        }
    }

    if($flag == 'mismatch'){
        break;
    }  
 }

echo $flag;
```

**Assumption 2**: Each table is compared by each row. I mean row1 table1 is compared with row1 table2 and than row2 table1 is compared with row2 table2.

```
$flag='';
foreach ($temp_answers as $key1=>$temp_answer) {
    foreach ($answers as $key2=>$answer) {
        if($key1 == $key2){
            if($answer == $temp_answer){
                $flag = $flag.'match ';
            }else {
                $flag = $flag.'mismatch ';
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo $flag;
```

Comment: hmmm...
i wanna ask. you want 'match' message returned if all data in column of each table is same. once data is different, you want message returned is 'mismatch'. am i right?

Comment: MISMATCH MISMATCH MISMATCH

Comment: assuming 3 data are being compared its tables

Comment: what i mean is the primary key/foreign on the other table, the value on that column matched the other echo match otherwise mismatch?

Comment: i have updated it. please check if that is what you want.

Comment: i did the assumption 2 but error, undefined offset:3 which i think its the $key var.

Comment: ups sorry my fault. $answers is not just array, but it is a result set. i have updated it..:)

Comment: i try the latest update but it echo only 2 flags, which in my table i have  3 data both tables. why its only echoing 2 flags?

Comment: are you sure? may you send result of print_r($temp_answers) and print_r($answers) please?

Comment: $flag=$flag.$flag.' ';  i am bother with this piece of code?

Comment: ok i have change temporary variable $flag to be $flags..:)
i think it will be run properly..:)

Comment: $temp_answers = [b, b, a]      ///   $answers = [b, b, a]

Comment: i just change $flag to $flags. i don't write variable $keys..:)
look and copy the code..^_^

Comment: when i change all the $flag to $flags the result are the same only two data are compared which is it echo 2 flags when i try to remove the $flags = $flags.flag it return 1 flags

Comment: ohhh i think this is a little miscommunication. not all, but just the temporary return..:)  are you re-copy the code? there are 2 variables, one $flag and one more $flags...:)

Comment: no i just tweak it the way because its undefined so i change all related to that variable ^_^

Comment: so after you re-copy, what is the result?

Comment: it should be three flags because in my DB i am comparing 3 answers

Comment: here is my algo. for the meantime i try it with flags but once i got the correct flow i will insert it to the pivot table i have made

Comment: i think its working, but wait i try with couple of inputs if its truely working tnx, would you mind if u wait? ^_^ sorry for my english, im not really good on it

Comment: heheh...
yeah nice i can help you...:)

Comment: thank you so much sir, it save me a lot of time, i've been doing it for my school project.. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Well I would have done it like this.

First give variables names that help you know what is in them

Second always use `{}` in `if else` even if there is only one line in the `if` or `else`, it makes it easier to see where things actually start and finish.

Then always use indentation as well so you can visually see where a block of code starts and finishes. Remember, you may have to come back to a piece of code weeks after writing it, so make it easy to read as it may be you that has to work out what you did.

Also when you output info about what matches or mismatches also include the data you need to see in order to tell that the matching is correct. Then if it does not do quite what you want you can easily see whats going wrong.

```
$temp_answers = array();
$questions = array();

$temp_answers = Tempanswer::where('subject_id', $subject_id)
                             ->where('student_id', $student_id)
                             ->lists('temp_answer');

$questions = Question::where('subject_slug', $subject->slug)
                             ->lists('letteranswer');

foreach ($temp_answers as $temp_answer) {

    foreach ($questions as $question ) {

        if($question == $temp_answer){
            echo "Question = $question TempAnswer = $temp_answer > MATCH" . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo "Question = $question TempAnswer = $temp_answer > MISMATCH" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: but again why is it only the last item in my array being compared in both table? will i try to put the same data on both table but the result will always like this base on your code

Comment: MISMATCH MISMATCH MATCH